# How do Import a .fil file from another project in Audit Command Language (ACL)?

Tags: database, audit

I need to import an Audit Command Language(ACL) table created in another project. The tables are saved out to .FIL (ex. FY12P12.FIL) files. When I use the GUI to import the table the resulting data is a jumbled mess.

I tried using this command:

```
IMPORT LAYOUT "\\mypath\FY12P12" to FY12P12_Table
```

resulting in this error:

File\mypath\FY12P1217.LAYOUT cannot be found

Is there any way to import this .FIL file and get good data?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that directly. In my opinion, you should open the FIL file in ACL and then export the data to a CSV or Excel file and then import it in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than importing the .fil, you should right click on the project name in the navigator and click copy from another project, then select table. Navigate to the original .acl project and select it.

[image: Copy from another Project]

Next, select the table that you want to copy.

[image: Select Tables to Copy]

The final step will be either pointing the table at the original .fil via "Link to New Source Data", or copying the .fil to the new project location so that ACL automatically finds the .fil.